# Anime sound bite repository?

Tags: resources

Does anyone know if a good anime sound bite repository exists? I know someone who is considering incorporating silly/hyperbolic/cute sound bites from various animes into her reviews as reactionary bits.

Unfortunately YouTube doesn't allow sorting or searching clips by time length (of seconds) and I haven't seen too much on archive.org. I can't think of other good sources aside from manual extraction.

Answer (score 2):

One that I know is [NiconiCommons (Japanese)](http://commons.nicovideo.jp/materials/) (sister site of NicoNicoDouga, a Japanese video sharing site). Basically it's a site where users can upload and share resources/materials (image, sound, video, etc) for people to use.

You can browse all the [audio materials](http://commons.nicovideo.jp/search/material/audio), or search the one you want.

> 1. Click *Advanced Search* button
>
>    [image: advanced search button]
> 2. Input the *Tag* or *Keyword* in Japanese
>
>    [image: input keyword]
> 3. Tick 音声 (*onsei*, audio) only
>
>    [image: audio only]
> 4. Press *Search* button
>
>    [image: search button]

Alternatively, replace the `[tag]` or `[keyword]` from these URL:

```
Tag-only     : http://commons.nicovideo.jp/search/tag/[tag]?s=d&o=d&t=2&sc=1
Keyword-only : http://commons.nicovideo.jp/search/keyword/[keyword]?s=d&o=d&t=2&sc=1
Tag & Keyword: http://commons.nicovideo.jp/search/hybrid/[tag]/[keyword]?s=d&o=d&t=2&sc=1
```

Example: [List of *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure* sound bites](http://commons.nicovideo.jp/search/tag/%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7?s=d&o=d&t=2&sc=1).

However, since these are all uploaded by users, you may not find what you want. You also need to have an account to be able to download, but the registration page is available in English.

Comment: This is definitely the type of service I was looking for, but I was hoping for something with more English clips. Thanks for sending it my way though.